# CentOS 8 - Clustered File System

Tags: centos, pacemaker, multipath-storage, pcs, gfs

In my environment, I have a need for a shared disk between two application servers such that changes on Server A are immediately available on Server B. Historically, I have solved this issue by sharing a GFS2 volume by using multipathed disks stored on our enterprise filer and attached using our virtualization solution.

This configuration requires fencing of the GFS2 nodes in the cluster and so I have used pacemaker to handle the fencing for GFS2 in the event that a node dies or becomes unhealthy to prevent full corruption of the file system by configuring [stonith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STONITH) to use [SBD fencing](http://linux-ha.org/wiki/SBD_Fencing) previously.

While gfs2-utils and fence-agents-sbd is available for CentOS, the pcs command is not available as of CentOS 8.0 and it appears that it may [never be available](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=16469) in the main repos. This is problematic as pcs was integral in configuring this in CentOS 7.

This leaves me wondering

- What can I do as an alternate for fencing the volume without having to compile the applicaiton from source (ongoing security updates & bug fixes is a requirement)
- If nothing, what can I use to provide a distributed & redundant storage solution in CentOS 8? An NFS server would be out of the question as a failure to the file server would take both application servers offline.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_distributed_file_systems

Comment: What about an HA NFS Cluster running on CentOS 7 (Pacemaker/Corosync/DRBD?).

Comment: @MattKereczman - Our enterprise filer is capable of serving a block device to an NFS server, but I do not know if it is able to support a DRBD configuration.

Comment: @JamesShewey If it's serving a block device, you could have it serve block-device-a to node-a, and block-device-b to node-b, and use DRBD to replicate the data between them. Then, use Pacemaker/Corosync/DRBD to build a shared-nothing HA NFS cluster.

Comment: @MattKereczman - The goal here is to upgrade to CentOS 8. Deploying other CentOS 7 servers defeats the purpose. That only takes me as far as the CentOS/RHEL 7 end of life.

Comment: It appears that CentOS *may* package this and add it to the repo eventually. See [BZ ID 16553](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=16553)

Answer (score 1):

As of Centos 8.1, pcs is back.  Just enable the Centos-HA repo.